# Why am I getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domNode' of null` from Tableau when executing Watir script?

Tags: rspec, cucumber, tableau-api, watir

I am using Watir automation to validate that a report open and I can see specific tab within that report.

I get a pop-up with the following information it.

> As the script enters the report an error window displays with the
>   following text: Unexpected Error An unexpected error occurred. If you
>   continue to receive this error please contact your Tableau Server
>   Administrator. Session ID: 297D9D39C3144E0EB94D2CDE4CF03339-1:0
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domNode' of null`

Console Error:

```
vqllegacydojouiweb.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domNode' of null
at Object.layout (vqllegacydojouiweb.js:2)
at Object.postCreate (vqllegacydojouiweb.js:2)
at Object.create (clientweb.js:16)
at Object.postscript (clientweb.js:16)
at Object._construct (dojo.js:16)
at new <anonymous> (dojo.js:16)
at s.createTabbedNavigation (vqllegacydojouiweb.js:2)
at E.<anonymous> (vqlweb.js:56)
at c (mscorlib.min.js:1)
at i (jquery-3.0.0.min.js:2)
```

If I navigate to the same report manually the above error message does not display and I am able to see the tab.

I searched multiple forums and could not find anything that relates to this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

selenium-webdriver (3.14.0)
watir (6.14.0)
webdrivers (3.4.1)

Chrome Version 72.0.3626.96 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Can you provide the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce the behavior?  And the specific `watir` code?

Comment: I have found one of the Chromedriver options is causing the issue. --user-agent

Comment: Glad that you got it worked out.  Can you please post your solution as an answer or delete your question?  Just keeping SO tidy...

Answer (score 0):

I have found one of the Chromedriver options is causing the issue. --user-agent